# Getting exception 'missing cash entry lines', but the aren't missing?

Tags: c#, exact-online

I'm using the exactonline-api-dotnet-client from GitHub to access ExactOnline from C#.
When I try to add a new Cash payment, I'm using the code:

```
var cashPayments = new List<ExactOnline.Client.Models.FinancialTransaction.CashEntryLine>();
cashPayments.Add(new ExactOnline.Client.Models.FinancialTransaction.CashEntryLine()
{ });
var cashPaymentsEnumerable = cashPayments.AsEnumerable();
var journalCode = "10"; //Code 10 = cashbook
var cash = new ExactOnline.Client.Models.FinancialTransaction.CashEntry()
{
    JournalCode = journalCode,
    CashEntryLines = cashPaymentsEnumerable
};
bool created = exactClient.For<ExactOnline.Client.Models.FinancialTransaction.CashEntry>().Insert(ref cash);
```

After the execution of the created line, an exception is raised:

```
Missing cash entry lines. Cash entry lines must be supplied to create a new cash entry.
```

Is this because the CashEntryLine is empty (is somewhere documented what fields are mandatory?
Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Well, obviously you need some data in the entry lines to be able to insert them. I would start by checking [the documentation](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=FinancialTransactionCashEntryLines).

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to see which fields are mandatory?

Comment: Unfortunately not. That would be useful indeed.